# ASP .NET Pass DateTime Value from Views to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

When in view mode, I try to fill in and get the date, it always turns out to be empty, but for example, the string field is filled in. And if I don't use the ViewModel, but only the Booking model, the date is filled in. I would like the date to be filled in with the viewmodel as well...

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CheckOut3(CheckoutModel broom)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(broom);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View(broom);
}
```

Model:

```
  public class Booking
  {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Room Room { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode =true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        public DateTime? CheckInDate{ get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        public DateTime? CheckOutDate { get; set; }
  }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class CheckoutModel
{
    public Booking booking {get; set;}
    public Room room { get; set; }

}
```

View:

```
<form asp-action="Checkout3">
    <div class="row">
        <!--Grid column-->
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 mb-4">
            <label asp-for="booking.CheckInDate">CheckIn</label>
            <input asp-for="booking.CheckInDate" class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="CheckInDate" />
            <span asp-validation-for="booking.CheckInDate" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <!--Grid column-->
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <label asp-for="booking.CheckOutDate">CheckOut</label>
            <input asp-for="booking.CheckOutDate" class="form-control" type="date" name="CheckOutDate" />
            <span asp-validation-for="booking.CheckOutDate" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Checkout" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are the remaining fields populated correctly?

Comment: Yes, and other fields are saved after the form is completed, but date = null, if I use Viewmodel. With the same code, when I use model Booking, date shows and saves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you're posting `CheckInDate` and `CheckOutDate` in the html form, while it should be `booking.CheckInDate` and `booking.CheckOutDate`. Remove the name in your view, so `name` will be set with the value provided in `asp-for`.

```
<!--Grid column-->
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 mb-4">
    <label asp-for="booking.CheckInDate">CheckIn</label>
    <input asp-for="booking.CheckInDate" class="form-control" type="datetime-local" />
    <span asp-validation-for="booking.CheckInDate" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<!--Grid column-->
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <label asp-for="booking.CheckOutDate">CheckOut</label>
    <input asp-for="booking.CheckOutDate" class="form-control" type="date" />
    <span asp-validation-for="booking.CheckOutDate" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for it, I'll know it for future)